# Compare and find strings in 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I am New to Matlab and I am stuck in efficiently solving the following problem.

I have two arrays (both of them 2D) and I want to check array1 col by col to know how many elements appear in each col of array2 (compare col to col)

for example

```
array1

    ---------
    'a1'  'b1'    'c1'   
    'd1'  'e1'    'f1'

array2
----------
    'a1'   'a1'   'b1'  'b1'  'a1' 
    'd1'   'd1'   'c1'  'd1'  'c1'
    'c1'   'c1'   'b1'  'd1'  'd1'
```

I am trying to get the following output

```
2 elements from array1 col1 appear in array2 col1
2 elements from array1 col1 appear in array2 col2
0 elements from array1 col1 appear in array2 col3
1 elements from array1 col1 appear in array2 col4
2 elements from array1 col1 appear in array2 col5

0 elements from array1 col2 appear in array2 col1
0 elements from array1 col2 appear in array2 col2
1 elements from array1 col2 appear in array2 col3
1 elements from array1 col2 appear in array2 col4
0 elements from array1 col2 appear in array2 col5

1 elements from array1 col3 appear in array2 col1
1 elements from array1 col3 appear in array2 col2
1 elements from array1 col3 appear in array2 col3
0 elements from array1 col3 appear in array2 col4
1 elements from array1 col3 appear in array2 col5
and so on
```

now I tried to do the below ugly code getting partial output

```
for i=1:size(Array1,2)
   for m=1:size(Array1,1)
     element = Array1(i,m);

     indx =find(ismember(Array2,element));
     Array_match(indx) = Array_match(indx) + 1;
     end
    for s=2:size(Array1,1)
    if  length(char(Array1(s,i))) > 0 
        tt= tt + 1;
    end
    length(Array_test_words(s,i))
    end
    Indx2 = find((Array_match) > tt);
 end
```

Comment: So it works and you would like input on how to improve the code or it does not work?

Comment: the behavior is not stable... when I try it one by one it works however, when I switch on the loop for one time run it gives me unexpected values.

Comment: Would those cells always have single character strings?

Comment: yes they always have N characters i mean if 1 char then all 1 char if 2 char then all elements will be 2 ...if we can do it for 1 or 2 chars will be enough for me

Comment: one more thnig, the size of array1 and array2 are unknow (only 2D)

Comment: Can you take oath that the data won't change again? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to the concatenation of both arrays to transform the cells into numeric labels. Remove repeated values in each column of the second array. Then test for equality with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and aggregate results for each combination of columns:

```
[~, ~, labels] = unique({array1{:} array2{:}});
a1 = reshape(labels(1:numel(array1)),size(array1)); %// array1 as numeric labels
a2 = reshape(labels(numel(array1)+1:end), size(array2)); %// same for array2
a2 = sort(a2);
a2(diff([NaN(1,size(a2,2)); a2])==0) = NaN; %// remove repeated values
m = bsxfun(@eq, permute(a1, [1 3 2]), permute(a2, [3 1 4 2])); %// find matches
result = squeeze(sum(reshape(m, [],size(a1,2),size(a2,2)), 1));
```

In your rexample this gives

```
result =
     2     2     0     1     2
     0     0     1     1     0
     1     1     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the input cell arrays have all the cells of single character strings, this might work for you -

```
%// Input cell arrays
array1 = {
    'a1' 'b1' 'c1'   
    'd1' 'e1' 'f1'}

array2 = {
        'a1'   'a1'   'b1'  'b1'  'a1' 
    'd1'   'd1'   'c1'  'd1'  'c1'
    'c1'   'c1'   'b1'  'd1'  'd1'}

%// Convert input cell arrays to numeric arrays
array1n = char(array1)-0
array1n = reshape(array1n(:,1) * 1000 + array1n(:,2),size(array1))

array2n = char(array2)-0
array2n = reshape(array2n(:,1) * 1000 + array2n(:,2),size(array2))

out = squeeze(sum(any(bsxfun(@eq,array2n,permute(array1n,[3 4 1 2])),1),3))
```

Output -

```
out =
     2     0     1
     2     0     1
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
     2     0     1
```

Comment: @Aabualia Please edit your question with some reproducible code that includes generating the input arrays, so that we could test out the codes.

Comment: error : To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Comment: @Aabualia Do both input cell arrays have all the cells of single character strings, as promised by you earlier in your comments?

Comment: @Aabualia hmm Please edit your question with something that is representative of such a data.

Comment: @Aabualia Check out the edits! [Luis's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25768033/3293881) deserves a look too!